# Switching channels without cutting video into clips in kdenlive

Tags: live, linux, transitions

I'm using KDEnlive to edit multiple videotracks. I have the tracks synched, but they are different lengths. In a preview of the video I can sort-of live edit by switching off different video-channels. The topmost active video will show.

What I would like to do is do this for my final edit. I don't want to cut the video's into pieces, because I might change my mind about where I want to transition over to another channel.

What I'd like to do is mark a spot on a channel where it changes to anouther channel (perhaps with a transition) and play around with these until I have the edit I want.

I imagine it's possible to transition from one channel to the other without actually deleting parts of the video and cutting channels up into clips?